# jQuery Variables or addClass()/removeClass() to Keep Track of Selected Element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is to keep track of an element that has an active Twitter Bootstrap popover. There can be only one such element at the same time. Here's the relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".word").on("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (!$(this).hasClass("popover-active")) {
            $(".popover-active").popover("hide");
            $(".popover-active").removeClass("popover-active");
            $(this).popover("show");
            $(this).addClass("popover-active");
        }
    });

});
```

As you can see above, I'm using `$().addClass` and `$().removeClass` to add and remove a `popover-active` class to the element with the active popover. But perhaps there's a better solution. I was thinking about using a variable to keep track of the selected element, as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $activePopover = $();

    $(".word").on("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this) !== $activePopover) {
            $activePopover.popover("hide");
            $(this).popover("show");
            $activePopover = $(this);
        }
    });

});
```

So my question is: Which method is better to use and why? Are there any other solutions that you can think of that are better than both of these?

Comment: your second method is good to use

Comment: The first one will modify the DOM, the second one will not.
The second option is faster and more maintainable.

Comment: I would advise for the second method. Keeping a reference to the element is not a hassle and you don't require your script to browse the whole DOM to retrieve the active element. Plus, the first could fail if your class is not removed for an unexpected error, and two popovers would show at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it a bit, and let the popover init happen either via javascript, or entirely via data attributes, with something like this which uses the built in events (*note that I removed the hyphen from your variable name. JS would interpret it as a minus, not a hyphen*):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $activePopover;

    $(document).on('show.bs.popover', function (e) {
        if ($activePopover) { $activePopover.popover('hide') }
        $activePopover = $(e.target);
    });

});
```

[**See it in action here**](http://www.bootply.com/NZNDprKJUQ)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the hyphen. Unfortunately I don't think using an event handler will work in this case. My actual code is a little more complicated -- I just posted the relevant part -- and requires me to manually trigger the popovers.

Answer (score 0):

I think keeping track with a class is the best solution, because the popover is bind to the element. If you introduce a variable you have to sync it to be sure it is relevant to the popover state. Also it allows you to switch to a different popover plugin which supports multiple instances.

I would do this:

```
$(".word").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass("popover-active");

    if ($(this).hasClass("popover-active")) {
        $(this).popover("show");

        return;
    }

    $(this).popover("hide");
});
```